# Revert changes from a single directory in git

Tags: git, git-revert

I cannot find a good match for this, but there must be a shorter way of doing this... Say we have a sub-tree of a project, picking [one at random here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commits/master/src/vs/editor/contrib/codelens), as a local repository and I want to rewind back to the December 11th revision 6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd, that is undo the six (at the time of writing) commits above. From reading the docs, I know I could do:

```
git revert commit1 commit2 commit3 commit4 commit5 commit6
```

But surely there must be an easier and more general way like, say:

```
git revert HEAD...6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd \
        src/vs/editor/contrib/codelens
```

That gives me "fatal: bad revision 'src/vs/editor/contrib/codelens'".

Of course, doing:

```
git checkout 6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd \
        src/vs/editor/contrib/codelens
```

Gives me the desired revision for the given directory, but I'd like to have a git-generated revert log for traceability, etc.

Comment: What if the commits have changes to other directories? Should those be reverted as well?

Comment: I shall assume they don't, but even if they do, I can use `git checkout` to revert them back to `HEAD` as desired, so we can ignore this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experimented and come to the conclusion this is not a good idea, but in the spirit of sharing, this is what I came up with. First, to get a list of versions to revert, I did:

```
git log --first-parent --no-merges --pretty=format:"%h" \
                  HEAD...6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd .
```

So, to feed that into git revert, I did:

```
git revert --no-commit $(git log --first-parent --no-merges --pretty=format:"%h" \
                  HEAD...6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd .)
```

However, on my own repository things got messy and there were lots of merge conflicts, so I just gave up and did:

```
git revert --abort
git checkout 6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd \
        src/vs/editor/contrib/codelens
```

Then manually added the results of:

```
git log --first-parent --no-merges --oneline \
                  HEAD...6b6e73b3e77176a8a80ae01a1844914102728acd .
```

To the commit message.

Comment: one remark : in general, the combination of `--first-parent` and `--no-merges` will probably hide steps which did modify your dir. I suggest you have a look at the list of commits you see with `--first-parent` alone, and with `--no-merges` alone